# Angular 9 package.json post build script running on Windows 10 - how to copy three files?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to build a Angular module on my local Windows 10 PC, and the 'package.json' file includes a 'postbuild' script that is meant to copy three files.

```
"postbuild": "cp ./README.md ./CHANGELOG.md ./LICENSE ./dist/angular-jwt/",
```

This post build script fails on my Windows 10 PC.  How can I fix this?

Comment: do yourself a favor and use a different shell like bash (included with the git installation for windows) or similar.

Answer (score 0):

this command works on my windows:

```
"postbuild": "copy .\\README.md .\\CHANGELOG.md .\\LICENSE .\\dist\\angular-jwt\\",
```

edit: copy doesn't work with several files.

```
 "postbuild": "robocopy .\\ .\\dist\\angular-jwt\\ README.md CHANGELOG.md LICENSE",
```

With this my npm outputs and error but it did copy the 2 files I tried to copy

Better alternatives if you face the same problem in the future would be to have  terminal which can understand unix commands